# Freeze Sheet position in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I have 2 sheets that always need to be the 1st and 2nd sheets.

1. 1st "Form responses 1" (linked to a form)
2. 2nd "Summary"

Everytime the form is filled it creates a new sheet, when this happens the "Summary" sheets moves down to 3rd place and subsequently lower down as more new sheets get created.

How can I freeze the position of the 2nd sheet so it doesnt move to the 3rd spot and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest thing do do would be control where the new sheet in placed with insertSheet(sheetName, sheetIndex). Sheets are 0 indexed, so:

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 ss.insertSheet('My New Sheet', 2);
```

would place the new sheet after the first two. Or, you could use getSheets() and determine the last sheet and insert the new sheet at the end.

Comment: So this is the code I'm using, I've updated the insertSheet(sheetName, sheetIndex) with ss.insertSheet(custname, 2); 

But get an error "Cannot call overloaded constructor insertSheet with parameters (number,number) "

function onSubmit(e){
  Logger.log('submit ran');
  
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();

  //Get last row of data
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  var custname = sheet.getRange(lastRow, 4).getValue();

  //create sheet name with customer no.
  ss.insertSheet(custname, 2);

Comment: Your script runs fine for me. The only error I get is if the custname sheet already exists. If you can share your spreadsheet or a sample of it, I will be happy to take a look.

Comment: Your right it works, the custname it was taking was a number, if its text, it works. Thanks a ton Ed, appreciate it!